# Connect to Azure Resource via VPN P2S on windows server 2012

Tags: azure

I can connect azure with windows 10 machine via Point-to-Site (P2S), but I cannot connect to the server 2012 and show error code 812.

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause:** Prompt 812 error is because the operating system defaults to TLS1.0 or 1.1 version, and the default VPNGW no longer supports both versions after July 1, 2018. You need to use the registry to add support for TLS1.2

**Solution:**
Run command of powershell as bellow.
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP\EAP\13 /v TlsVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 0xfc0

reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp" /v DefaultSecureProtocols /t REG_DWORD /d 0xaa0

if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% EQU AMD64 reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp" /v DefaultSecureProtocols /t REG_DWORD /d 0xaa0